# Clients want to copy/paste from word processors; rich text editors will make it a mess. How do we solve this?

Tags: content-management-system, ms-word, richtextbox

After years of experience with custom made CMS systems, I come to this conclusion:

- Clients *really* want to copy and paste information from word processors into their website CMS. They don't like to create large texts in a website box, and prefer to do so from their good old word processor. Or they simply have their text already prepared for other purposes, and therefore want to copy and paste.
- Clients do not like to lose their format. They've spent time on their boldface text, headings, etc, and they do not like to do this all over again.
- Rich Text Format fields (TinyMCE, CKEditor, etc) are not yet able to properly convert all formatted text into the right HTML. I do not blame them; this has to be very difficult given the odd 'source code' that word processors put in the clipboard. But reading all SO topics about richttext related issues, I feel this is a known limitation.

What do you do in such cases? I've tried the following:

- Explain the client beforehand that this is not a word processor we are implementing, and it has limitations. They can understand, but still want to copy and paste.
- Only show very few buttons for formatting (bold, italic, links). That way, we can strip the tags and clean this up quite well, and this limits issues. Works better, but clients keep asking for font options, more colors, headers, etc.

So not a really good solution in sight. Are there others who have tackled this issue successfully?

Answer (score 1):

One solution (and probably the best I've come up with) is to post-process the pasted content.  So, catch the publish event and correct all the crappy HTML -- catch all the "mso-normal" styles, for instance, and remove them.  You'd have a set of rules which clean stuff coming out of, say, MS Word.

Though, this is not just a word processing problem.  You're pasting from one rich text editor to another, and styles just don't transfer between rich editing environments.  This is not so much a technical problem as it is a logical problems.

**Update:** Someone pointed me to this: [Copy-Pasting Word to your Web CMS](http://www.realstorygroup.com/Blog/2169-Copy-Pasting-Word-to-Your-Web-CMS).  No real solutions, but just confirmation that it's a sticky problem.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with you:

Last week I did a very interesting test with a customer for which I had to prepare some demo's of .NET based CMS systems (Umbraco, Sitefinity, DNN, Composite C1 ect). The customer himself had a Drupal based site and I was ashamed none of my CMS demo's did a 100% job with a complicated Word table (Ceteris paribus: I did not do some CMS fine-tuning, used every CMS out of the box). The worst part was his Drupal CMS did a 100% good job! It was exactly the same as it was in Word. For a client working a lot with Word my CMS-ses were a showstopper. Of course there are a lot of discussions on the web about 'you should not copy from Word' or 'do NOT use Word for CMS things'. Fact is: clients work with Word so we should deal with it.